# JavaScript Redirect not working with ?fbclid=

Tags: javascript, arrays, blogger

the community! 
I'm going through some issues. the redirection feature doesn't work well when I try to post the link on the Facebook platform. in general, the redirection only works outside facebook community. when I click on the shared link on Facebook automatically set this parameter at the end of URL ?fbclid=

example : https://myblog.blogspot.com/go/fb?fbclid=

but when I put the link directly on the browser works properly

here is my code

```
 <script language='javascript'>



    //<![CDATA[
    var key = window.location.href.split("go/")[1].replace("/","")
    var urls={
     'fb':'https://www.facebook.com', 
    }
    if(key){
     if(urls[key]){
     window.location.href=urls[key]
     }else{
     document.write("'"+key+"' not found ");
     }
    }
    //]]>
    </script>
```

Comment: Hi Omar, thank you for using StackOverflow! Please try to explain clearer and further your question. Also providing the expected behavior may help!

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.location.pathname` instead of `window.location.href`.

```xml
<script>
//<![CDATA[
  var key = window.location.pathname.split("go/")[1].replace("/","")
  var urls={
    'fb':'https://www.facebook.com', 
  }
  if(key){
    if(urls[key]){
      window.location.href=urls[key]
    } else {
      document.write("'"+key+"' not found ");
    }
  }
//]]>
</script>
```